# Ember.JS: Ember-Objects and where they are exported to

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to grasp the underlying system of **Ember.JS**. Whereto are those Ember-Objects **exported** and how are they used?

*components*:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({ ... });
```

*controllers*:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({ ... });
```

*models*:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({ ... });
```

*routes*:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({ ... });
```

... they all follow the same structure: they extend some object and export something.

Somebody knows more? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are interpreting the `export` keyword wrong here.

It doesn't mean files are written somewhere else in a different format, but:

> *if a module (= file) is `import`ed, then things in that file that are `export`ed are available* to the importer.

Think of it as making some parts available to other modules, a public API in shorter terms.

Ember files usually only export one thing as there is a strong naming convention making the Ember engine work that way.
This is why if you declare a `/user` route, it will try to use your `routes/user.js`, `controllers/user.js`, and `templates/user.hbs` files if they exist, without you having to specify anything.
In a similar way, this is what makes a component usable inside a template.

Hence the one-liner `export default Ember.Something.extend({ ... });` you find in these files.

However, you can have modules (= files) with multiple `export` statements in a single file, this is perfectly valid.

```
// Example from babel website

// lib/mathplusplus.js
export * from "lib/math";
export var e = 2.71828182846;
export default function(x) {
    return Math.exp(x);
}
// app.js
import exp, {pi, e} from "lib/mathplusplus";
console.log("e^π = " + exp(pi));
```

The [Learn ES2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules) from Babel website has a few examples, and you can read more about the `export` statement on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

In Ember applications, you will - from my experience - find files with multiple exports mostly in some directories meant to be used by more than one module in the application, or not bound to the Ember engine auto-import, like some utils.

The following example shows an `Ember.Controller` importing a variable exported from another module:

```
// utils/messages.js
export var hello = 'Hello!';
export var bye = 'Good Bye!'

// controllers/hello.js
import { hello } from "utils/messages";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firstName: 'David',

  helloString: Ember.computed('firstName', function(){
    return `${hello} ${this.get('firstName')}`;
  })
});
```

Comment: aaaah, okay, so I have to **import** stuff in files that _rely_ on other files?

Comment: "export" makes them visible to node ??

Comment: Yes, you need to use the `import` statement in order to use modules. Also, since this is an ES2015 feature, I think this is currently not available in nodejs unless you use a transpiler like Babel.

Comment: okay. i understand. :D I think it will work inside Ember.JS because Ember.JS is build upon ES2015 ?? isn't it?!!

Comment: Yes, it is indeed build with ES2015 settings.